# my flex-strech property doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I'm trying to use stretch property for three divs but It doesn't work and my divs just get the flex-start property .here is my code:

```css
 .flex-container{
         display:flex;
         height: 800px;
         background-color: rgb(100 , 100 , 100);
         flex-flow: wrap row;
         justify-content: stretch;
    
    }
    .item{
        height: 20vw;
        width: 20vw;
        background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="item first"></div>
            <div class="item second"></div>
            <div class="item third"></div>
            </div>
  
    </body>
```

Comment: What result do you want to get in the end? Should blocks be adaptive?

Comment: yes ,I want the blocks to cover all the free space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `flex-grow` in children**

```css
 .flex-container{
         display:flex;
         height: 800px;
         background-color: rgb(100 , 100 , 100);
  
         justify-content: stretch;
    
    }
    .item{
        flex-grow:1;
        height: 20vw;
        width: 20vw;
        background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="item first"></div>
            <div class="item second"></div>
            <div class="item third"></div>
            </div>
  
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

just give flex:auto to item

```
 .item{
    flex:auto;
 }
```